# UIButton not clickable under UIImageView (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

Thanks for reading.

My program adds UIImageViews upon tapping inside a UICollectionViewCell. Once the image is added, there is a separate, static UIButton set to delete any image(s) which intersect the button. The deleting code works fine, but the problem is that the button is not clickable under the programatically-added UIImageView. (If I click on a portion of the button which is not covered by the UIImageView, the button's function is called and the image(s) are properly deleted.)

**Edit:** I move the added image views around the screen using a UIGestureRecognizer and the handlepan function.

I have tried view.bringSubviewToFront(UIButton). After doing this, the button worked fine, but now the button was over the UIImageView, so I couldn't move the image outside of the button.

**Edit 2:** I found a workaround which bypasses the button functionality all together and simply deletes the image if its view intersects the button view at the end of the pan gesture.

//I added this code to the end of the handlepan function (and made a function calleddeleteimage which performs the actions of delete image):

```
if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        calleddeleteimage()
        }
```

//Here is my original code for the UIPanGestureRecognizer and for the UIButton:

`func handlepan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let movingview = recognizer.view!
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(movingview)
    movingview.center = CGPoint(x: movingview.center.x + translation.x, y: movingview.center.y + translation.y)

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(hungryman)

}


@IBOutlet weak var hungryman: UIButton!

@IBAction func deleteimage(sender: AnyObject) {

    var count = 0
    indexestodelete = []

    for i in unlockeddisplaying {


        if i.frame.intersects(hungryman.frame) {

            i.removeFromSuperview()
            indexestodelete.append(count)
        }
        count = count + 1

    }

    count = 0

    for i in indexestodelete {

        unlockeddisplaying.removeAtIndex(i - count)
        unlockeddisplayingtypes.removeAtIndex(i - count)
        count = count + 1

    }
}`

Thanks!

**TL;DR:** How to make UIButton always clickable, even when hidden under UIImageView?

Answer (score 2):

On your image view, set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` and touches will pass through it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I move the image view around using the handlepan function, so would't this make the images unmovable? I'll give it a try.